# How can I change the month of a time object?

Tags: ruby, time

I have a 2 time objects, one object has a greater month:

```
t = Time.new(2017, 8, 1)
n = Time.new(2017, 9, 1)
```

How can I set the month of both objects with only one input?

I thought something like this would work:

```
month1 = gets   #This works
month2 = month1 + 1

t = Time.new(2017, month1, 1)   #This works too
n = Time.new(2017, month2, 1)   #But this doesn't work
```

Comment: If that is your code, it should crash _before_ `t = Time.new(2017, month1, 1)`

Comment: Hint: you can't add a number to a string.

Comment: Why? It runs very well.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Put that code in a file and run the file.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev But i dont understand, i thought that i create not a String object with Time.new. Ohh, okay i understand where i fail. I read in a string and need to convert it to a int.

Comment: @Alassar as Sergio said, you cannot add a number to a string. You have to convert a string to a number first. For example, `month1 = gets.to_i`

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsec 
My Code fails not where you think it would. The string is converted automatically into an integer, but i cant add a number to the string and when i tried it, it failed. I thought that there is a method where you can change the month of a Time-Object. Thank you, you opend my eyes. *laugh*

Comment: @Alassar also be careful with this because if I enter any number outside of the range `(1..11)` this will fail as well since it will result in an invalid month

Comment: @Alassar: no, it fails _exactly_ where I think it would, at `month2 = month1 + 1`.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thats the reason why i wanted to asked, beacuse it is a dirty solution to my problem. I found no method in the time class where you can change the month of the Time-Object. Maybe i need to read it in through a if-clause where you cann only input a number between `(1..11)` and when i read in a 12 i need to add one year.

Comment: @Alassar might I suggest `DateTime` or just `Date` instead since time seems to have nothing to do with the actual question, As you eluded to `Time` is obviously concerned about the "Time" aspects and `Date` is concerned about the "Date" aspects but `DateTime` inherits from `Date` and includes some nice time like features. `Date#>>` is really what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> month1 = gets.to_i
> 5
> month2 = month1 + 1
> t = Time.new(2017, month1, 1)
#=> 2017-05-01 00:00:00 +0530 
> n = Time.new(2017, month2, 1)
#=> 2017-06-01 00:00:00 +0530
```

**Note:**

- You just need to convert user's input to integer.
- in your code `month2 = month1 + 1` , month1 is `String` and you are adding an integer value which is throwing you an error

---

### In Rails:

If you are using rails then there is **[Time#change](https://apidock.com/rails/Time/change)** inbuilt method is available, you can change any parameter with any of these keys: `:year`, `:month`, `:day`, `:hour`, `:min`, `:sec`, `:usec :nsec` of time object

for eg:

```
> Time.new(2017, 8, 1)
#=> 2017-08-01 00:00:00 +0530 
> Time.new(2017, 8, 1).change(month: 7)
#=> 2017-07-01 00:00:00 +0530
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this instead since your question clearly disregards the time portion of the object any way and your solution will have to handle cases in which the value is not between 1 and 11 otherwise an error will be raised for the month being out of range:

```
require 'date'
loop do 
    puts "Enter the first month:"
    @first_month = gets.to_i
    if (1..12).include?(@first_month)
      break
    else
      puts "Incorrect value a month must be between 1 and 12."
      puts "Please Try Again."
    end
end

t = Date.new(2017,@first_month,1)
n = t >> 1
```

This uses `Date#>>` which simply returns a new `Date` object incremented by n month(s). For example

```
d = Date.new(2017,11,1)
d >> 1
#=> #<Date: 2017-12-01 ((2458089j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
d >> 2
#=> #<Date: 2018-01-01 ((2458120j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# It can accept negative numbers too 
# Although this is usually represented as d << 10
d >> -10
#=> #<Date: 2017-01-01 ((2457755j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
d >> -10 == d << 10
#=> true
```

Answer (score -1):

The only thing i need to do, is to convert the string i read in, to an integer:

```
month1 = gets.to_i
```

Then my code runs very well.